# Load script after Ajax call not work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax call:

```js
$('#opt').change(function() {
  var option = $("#cdc").val();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "orari_pause/select_spaccato.php",
    data: 'option=' + option,
    success: function(whatigot) {
      $('#spaccato').html(whatigot);
    }, //END OF SUCCESS
    complete: function() {
      $.getScript("orari_pause/script_opener.js", function() {
      });
    } //END OF COMPLETE
  }); 
});
```

**script_opener.js**

```js
$(function() {
  $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    title: 'Dettaglio sessioni',
    height: 600,
    width:800,
    modal:true,
    resizable: false
  });

  $( ".opener" ).click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $( "#dialog" ).load( "orari_pause/dettaglio_sessioni.php?id="+id );
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
    $('.ui-widget-overlay').css('background', 'silver');
  });

  $( "#dialog2" ).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    title: 'Inserimento sessione',
    height: 380,
    width:300,
    modal:true,
    resizable: false
  });

  $( ".opener_session" ).click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $( "#dialog2" ).load( "orari_pause/form_nuova_sessione.php?id="+id );
    $( "#dialog2" ).dialog( "open" );
    $('.ui-widget-overlay').css('background', 'silver');
  });
});
```

In `select_spaccato.php` I have a button with class `opener_session`. When I click on it, the event doesn't fire (but the script is loaded correctly). I think is a problem with DOM... I also try to search into Stackoverflow forum with no results.

Can you help me?

**EDIT**
I try to load the JavaScript code inside `whatigot` variable, same results. The JS code is loaded, but the events not work.

Comment: Are you sure to send your option data correctly? I think you should use var option= $(this).val(); add to question HTML structures so that I could reflect your problem at home

Comment: Yes, the page returns correctly. The opener_session elements in it, on click, not fires event (script_opener.js, in "complete" function)

Comment: you can use $.when . you can refer https://css-tricks.com/multiple-simultaneous-ajax-requests-one-callback-jquery/ or try loading script  in sucess function itself

Comment: Does the other click handler work, the one on the `".opener"` element(s)?

Comment: No, the script is loaded inside of page, but not works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use event delegation

```
$('body').on('click',".opener",function() {

$('body').on('click',".opener_session",function() {
```

Comment: Why would that be necessary? The element in question is added dynamically, but the script that calls `.click()` is run *after* that, isn't it?

Comment: a better question is why load another js file when you can paste the content of that file in the success/complete function?